# User profile tabs only for current user

Tags: users, routes

On my user profile I have various tabs (view, my bookmarks, translate, ...). the problem ist, those tabs should only be visible for profile owner and not if I visit another profile.

Some of those tabs (bookmarks, submissions) are set via view: user/%/submissions with a menu tab - the permissions here are set. But how do I set permission for those tabs only to the current user?

Answer (score 0):

Alter menu and set `'access callback' => 'user_access'`
Or if you have custom profile tpl then render tabs like this:

```
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1)){
  //*******render tabs here*********/
}
```

Comment: if I set  `$items['user/%/view']['access callback'] = 'user_access'` I can't the see tab, even if I am on my own profile. Also do I have to set this for every single tab?

Comment: /**
     * Implementing hook_menu_alter
     * Restrict MENU TABS access
     */
 global $user;
    function MODULE_NAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
        if(isset($user) || $user->uid !=0) {
            $items['user/%user/yourtabname1']['access callback'] = FALSE;
             $items['user/%user/yourtabname2']['access callback'] = FALSE;
                   //Change the MENU PATH as per your requirement.
        }
    }
Yes ,you have to set permission for each tab.